# Hex number in Python and endianess

Tags: python, hex

Will Python allways store the hex number, for example, 0x0FFF as 4095 or would it be dependent from the processor endianness?
I'm just assigning that hex value to a variable as:

```
var = 0x0FFF
```

I'm wondering if it is portable or not.
I have to do that way because is easier to mantain as the variable will correspond to what is stated on the official documents.